# How to route a file based on Size in Apache Camel

Tags: xml, configuration-files, apache-camel

Ok so still busy working with the file to MySQL file consumer. I started running into errors with certain large files and want to send them to another route for processing. So the idea is a simple Content Based Router that will look at the filesize and if it is a big file copy it to another directory and leave it there(once again simple steps to understand how to do it).

So I started reading about the CBR and how to use the simple expression language inside of my camel context. So I added a CBR to the camel-context.xml file and now I cant even run any routes. The build fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Line 48 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml] is invalid; 
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

Right so obviously I got some bad XML in there, but for the live of me I cant seem to find the problem maybe some of the more experienced riders can give me some advise here by taking a quick look at my xml file.

```
 <errorHandler id="defaultEH" type="DefaultErrorHandler">
        <redeliveryPolicy
                 maximumRedeliveries="5"
                 retryAttemptedLogLevel="WARN"
                 backOffMultiplier="1"
                 useExponentialBackOff="true"/>
     </errorHandler>
    <threadPoolProfile id="myDefaultProfile"
        defaultProfile="true"

        maxPoolSize="16"/>

        <threadPool id="myPool" threadName="Cool" poolSize="4" maxPoolSize="4" maxQueueSize="100"/>
        <route handleFault="true">


            <from uri="file://c:/CTest/BadFiles?noop=true&amp;recursive=true&amp;delay=3000"/>
            <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${file:length}<20000000</simple>
                <threads executorServiceRef="myPool">
                    <to uri="bean://fileToSQL"/>
                </threads>
            </when>
            <otherwise>

                <to uri="file://c:/CTest/outbox"/>

                <stop/>
            </otherwise>
            </choice>
            <!--<to uri="jdbc://timlogdb"/>-->

       </route>
```

I looked at everywhere and according to my understanding this should be valid XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to escape the bigger than sign in the  text; this is XML restriction.
Also the simple language requires that you use space around its operators. So it should be

```
<simple>${file:length} &lt; 20000000</simple>
```

Comment: I thought it was something stupid. Been working on too much today think it is time for a ice cold beer. Thanks